# How do you reference local files in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: aptana

I know a similar question has been asked, except I just can't get it to work after trying the solution multiple times.

So I have a workspace folder, and "Website" folder inside there.

/Workspace/Website/

Then I have files inside that website files such as index.htm and style.css and a folder called test.

From the test folder, I want to reference style.css from the "/Website/" folder.

When I link using src="/style.css", the url becomes "/Workspace/style.css". I don't want the root to be "/workspace", I want it to be "/Website".

How do I do this?
I already tried the Web Server Preview, I made the Base URL: http://localhost:2020/, then the document root: /C:...Workspace\Website

Still, style.css isn't references from the website folder, instead from the workspace. How do i fix this? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the same situation referencing an image. I had to include the full path.
In your case `url(http://127.0.0.1:2020/Workspace/Website/style.css)`

Comment: Ahh, but thats the problem I want all the URL's to work when they are uploaded directly to my site. On my site I don't have a "workspace" folder. How do I make links relative to just my project folder.

Comment: It all seems pretty screwy - there must be a simple solution. I tried turning workspace folder into a project folder and it just created a new folder called workspace inside workspace! There must be a way to make website the root directory but I haven't found it.

Comment: alritey, yeah its weird. I just ended up referencing links like this "../folder/file.txt"